# "Sleep" execution inside asynchronous iteration "for await" (ES2018)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-2018

I am using asynchronous iteration for getting items from DynamoDB. For every iteration (item) I execute some http requests. I need to "sleep" 1 second in every iteration in order to limit the request flow. I tried with promisify(setTimeout) but the execution stops.

```
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout)

for await (const item of mapper.scan(MyDomainObject)) {

    await sleep(1000);   //This doesn't work
    // do some http requests
}
```

What it's the proper way to "sleep" inside a "for await" interation?

Comment: ...you can't use `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Stuart it doesn't work inside the await

Comment: I don't think you can do this elegantly within the asynchronous loop. I would add the http request content to a queue and then make those requests iteratively, or two at a time, or whatever limit you want (but asynchronously to the loop, since I'm assuming `scan` or something else is expensive, if it's not then making the loop asynchronous is a little silly)

Comment: @rtpax Yes, the scan is expensive (around 200K rows). The problem about your solution is that for every loop I will do like 20 request. That would be like 4000 requests payloads, headers, etc. to be stored in memory, which is too much. I think it must be a solution to do it inside the for await.

Comment: What exactly is `mapper.scan`? Does it support `for await`?

Comment: @Bergi, it's an AWS DynamoDB API and it does support it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-amazon-dynamodb-datamapper-for-javascript-developer-preview/

Comment: Hm, it only says that the asynchronous iterators "*automatically continue fetching new pages of results until you break out of the loop.*" It doesn't use any `await` in the loop body of the example, and it says nowhere that the iterator supports backpressure. It might as well fetch results as fast as possible, and use the iterator only as an interface to access them. You might want to open a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that I was executing the code with **Jest**. When I executed the code normally the above code works perfectly. Thanks to Noseratio answer I looked elsewhere. I was too focused in the for await.

Comment: You still should be able to use async/await in your jest tests: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct, I've simulated your asynchronous generator like this:

```
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

async function* scan(arg) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(`yielding ${i}`);
    await sleep(500);
    yield i;
  }
}

async function test()
{
  for await (let item of scan({})) {
    console.log(`got ${await item}`);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
}

test();
```

The execution doesn't stop for me, no matter how many iterations I provision for inside `scan`.

Thus, it's not the `sleep` that's causing the problem, you should be looking elsewhere. Perhaps, the issue is with `mapper.scan`, or with those http requests, or maybe you just need to upgrade your node.js (I'm on v10.11.0).

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution. Thanks.